# Getting two class game to interact

Tags: python, class, function

So I know this site gets far too many questions about Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way, but I'm going through ex42., extra credit #3, has got me hung up.

I am having trouble getting the class Engine to effectively start and transition into the class Map where the game can begin going through the different functions that I have defined

the code is as follows:

```
from sys import exit  
from random import randint

class Map(object):

    def death(): 
        print quips[randint (0, len(quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

    def princess_lives_here():
        print "You see a beautiful Princess with a shiny crown."
        print "She offers you some cake."

        eat_it = raw_input(">")

        if eat_it == "eat it":
            print "You explode like a pinata full of frogs."
            print "The Princess cackles and eats the frogs. Yum!"
            return 'death'

        elif eat_it == "do not eat it":
            print "She throws the cake at you and it cuts off your head."
            print "The last thing you see is her munching on your face. Yum!"
            return 'death'

        elif eat_it == "make her eat it":
            print "The Princess screams as you cram the cake in her mouth."
            print "Then she smiles and cries and thank you for saving her."
            print "She points to a tiny door and says, 'The Koi needs cake too.'"
            print "She gives you the very last bit of cake and shoves you in."
            return 'gold_koi_pond'

        else:
            print "The Princess looks at you confused and just points at the cake."
            return 'princess_lives_here'


class Engine(Map):

    def _init_(self, start):
        self.quips = [
            "You died. You suck at this.",
            "Your mom would be proud, if she were smarter",
            "Such a luser.",
            "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
        ]
        self.start = start

    def play(self):
        next = self.start

        while True:
            print "\n-----"
            room = getattr(self, next)
            next = room()

e = "princess_lives_here".Map.Engine
e.play()
```

---

Now the issue is not with the other functions within Map class but making the transition from the class Engine to class Map so the game can continue. It is either not defining 'Map' within the class Engine or in the variable i am setting up at the end and trying to run with the play() command.

Any other links you can point me to in regards to class interaction would be great. thnx again

Comment: Shouldn't it be `e = Engine("princess_lives_here")`?

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot wrong here.

Your code as shown is illegally indented; it looks like `__init__()` and `play()` should be indented to be members of class Engine, and `death()` and `princess_lives_here()` indented into Map.

The `__init__` of a class needs double underscores, not single, on each end.

The line:

```
e = "princess_lives_here".Map.Engine
```

is nonsensical python; it starts by trying to find a "Map" attribute in a string. If you want to instance a new object of a class, you'd say

```
e = Engine( "princess_lives_here" ) # or Map( "...")?
```

It's unclear to me what you need both Map and Engine for, but I'm guessing you either want Map to be a subclass of Engine (Engine is generic to all games and Map is specific to this game) or you want them to be separate objects, where an Engine and a Map refer back to each other.

As it stands you have Engine as a subclass of Map. If they're supposed to be separate, declare Engine as an object, have its `__init__` take both a starting point and a map instance, and do

```
m = Map()
e = Engine( m, "princess_lives_here" )
```

Comment: Actually, if you click 'edit', the code is correctly indented. Maybe markdown is being fussy?

Comment: @ Russell - i wrote question incorrectly. had the init(), play(), death(),  and princess_lives_here() correctly indented in my code. but thx for heads up on init function. now after i corrected them to be separate and setting up Engine as an object i am getting: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)...in my understanding that error is occuring as I have self, start, and quips in there. pls advise on how to correct the number of arguments i am giving to the __init__() fcn

Comment: Constructor calls get an implicit 'self', so e = Engine( "princess_lives_here", quips ) requires __init__( self, start, quips ).

Comment: By using m = Map() e = Engine( m, "princess_lives_here" )  and adding __init__( self, start, quips ) - i get the following response: getattr(): attribute name must be string...given that I created Map() it seems that getattr() should simply grab the fcn we designate within class Map which we designated as 'princess_lives_here'

Comment: The parameters passed in the Engine() call need to match the parameters named in the __init__() for class Engine, except for the 'self'. So Engine(m,"princess_lives_here") needs __init__(self,map_to_use,start), not __init__( self, start, quips ).

Answer (score 1):

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Map(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.quips = [
    "You died. You kinda suck at this.",
    "Your mom would be proud. If she were smarter.",
    "Such a luser.",
    "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
    ]

def death(self):
    print self.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
    exit(1)


def princess_lives_here(self):
    print "You see a beautiful Princess with a shiny crown."
    print "She offers you some cake."
    eat_it = raw_input("> ")

    if eat_it == "eat it":
        print "You explode like a pinata full of frogs."
        print "The Princess cackles and eats the frogs. Yum!"
        return 'death'

    elif eat_it == "do not eat it":
        print "She throws the cake at you and it cuts off your head."
        print "The last thing you see is her munching on your torso. Yum!"
        return 'death'

    elif eat_it == "make her eat it":
        print "The Princess screams as you cram the cake in her mouth."
        print "Then she smiles and cries and thanks you for saving her."
        print "She points to a tiny door and says, 'The Koi needs cake too.'"
        print "She gives you the very last bit of cake and shoves you in."
        return 'gold_koi_pond'

    else:
        print "The princess looks at you confused and just points at the cake."
        return 'princess_lives_here'

def gold_koi_pond(self):
    print "There is a garden with a koi pond in the center."
    print "You walk close and see a massive fin poke out."
    print "You peek in and a creepy looking huge Koi stares at you."
    print "It opens its mouth waiting for food."

    feed_it = raw_input("> ")

    if feed_it == "feed it":
        print "The Koi jumps up, and rather than eating the cake, eats your arm."
        print "You fall in and the Koi shrugs than eats you."
        print "You are then pooped out sometime later."
        return 'death'

    elif feed_it == "do not feed it":
        print "The Koi grimaces, then thrashes around for a second."
        print "It rushes to the other end of the pond, braces against the wall..."
        print "then it *lunges* out of the water, up in the air and over your"
        print "entire body, cake and all."
        print "You are then pooped out a week later."
        return 'death'

    elif feed_it == "throw it in":
        print "The Koi wiggles, then leaps into the air to eat the cake."
        print "You can see it's happy, it then grunts, thrashes..."
        print "and finally rolls over and poops a magic diamond into the air"
        print "at your feet."
        return 'bear_with_sword'

    else:
        print "The Koi gets annoyed and wiggles a bit."
        return 'gold_koi_pond'


def bear_with_sword(self):
    print "Puzzled, you are about to pick up the fish poop diamond when"
    print "a bear bearing a load bearing sword walks in."
    print '"Hey! That\' my diamond! Where\'d you get that!?"'
    print "It holds its paw out and looks at you."

    give_it = raw_input("> ")

    if give_it == "give it":
        print "The bear swipes at your hand to grab the diamond and"
        print "rips your hand off in the process. It then looks at"
        print 'your bloody stump and says, "Oh crap, sorry about that."'
        print "It tries to put your hand back on, but you collapse."
        print "The last thing you see is the bear shrug and eat you."
        return 'death'

    elif give_it == "say no":
        print "The bear looks shocked. Nobody ever told a bear"
        print "with a broadsword 'no'. It asks, "
        print '"Is it because it\'s not a katana? I could go get one!"'
        print "It then runs off and now you notice a big iron gate."
        print '"Where the hell did that come from?" You say.'
        return 'big_iron_gate'

def big_iron_gate(self):
    print "You walk up to the big iron gate and see there's a handle."

    open_it = raw_input("> ")

    if open_it == 'open it':
        print "You open it and you are free!"
        print "There are mountains. And berries! And..."
        print "Oh, but then the bear comes with his katana and stabs you."
        print '"Who\'s laughing now!? Love this katana."'
        return 'death'

    else:
        print "That doesn't seem sensible. I mean, the door's right there."
        return 'big_iron_gate'


class Engine(object):

def __init__(self, o, map):
    self.map = map
    self.obj = o

def play(self):
    nextmap = self.map

    while True:
        print "\n--------"
        room = getattr(self.obj, nextmap)
        nextmap = room()


a_map = Map()
a_eng = Engine(a_map, "princess_lives_here")

a_eng.play()
```